# Understanding Object Chaining

Tags: javascript

I am learning about object/method chaining in JavaScript and I would like make sure I understand it correctly.

If the following code is an example of JavaScript without object chaining:
`var people = helper.getPeople();`
`var bob = people.find("bob");`
`var email = bob.getEmail();`

and the code below is after applying object chaining:
`var email = helper.getPeople().find("bob").getEmail();`

Am I to consider object chaining as simply a way to "drill down" into an object, reaching "sub-objects" or properties/methods etc...?

If these two examples of code are supposed to do the same thing, why is a `var` declaration not required in the object-chained example? I do not understand how the chained statement is the same if no new variables are declared in the process.

I can see the value of saving space and writing the code on one line, and all my research online has shown that this is considered an intuitive, simplified way to write. However, I feel that I am able to read the first example (without object chaining) better. That may just be because I am new to JavaScript, but which example would be considered good coding practice?

Additionally, is the purpose of object chaining merely to reach objects that are not defined in the global scope? A way of reaching local objects?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: They are functionally the same. The var declaration is still there, it's just only saving the final call, . getEmail in this case. The two other functions still return their respective results, they just aren't being stored in a variable and are instead immediately used by the next function call.

Comment: why make more vars than needed? i hardly use var since i went all functional (exaggeration), and i think it's a good thing.

Comment: A reason to use the first example is to handle errors in any of the calls. If you are unsure whether *getPeople* will return a "people" or not, you need to test the result before calling the *find* method. One strategy to avoid this is to return empty instances when a call fails, but then you get silent failures and at the end don't know which part failed (was there no person? no one named bob? Did bob not have an email?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I to consider object chaining as simply a way to "drill down" into an object, reaching "sub-objects" or properties/methods etc...? Is the purpose of object chaining merely to reach objects that are not defined in the global scope? A way of reaching local objects?

It could be. Every of these methods does return *another object with methods*, that's the secret of chaining. "Drilling down" might be an appropriate wording for some uses, like the one you've shown, where different objects are returned.

However, whether these returned objects are hidden, local "sub-objects", accessible through other means or just created on the fly by that method, or even the original object that returns itself, is dependent on the methods and API design. All options make valid chaining, though.

> If these two examples of code are supposed to do the same thing, why is a var declaration not required in the object-chained example? I do not understand how the chained statement is the same if no new variables are declared in the process.

Returning objects that are immediately accessed does not require them to be assigned to any variable. They of course are held in memory somewhere, but don't have an explicit identifier attached to them.

> That may just be because I am new to JavaScript, but which example would be considered good coding practice?

Depends. Usually, a good practise is not to create variables if you don't need them. If you are only interested in the email and won't access all the `people` and `bob` again, there's no reason to create variables for them.

The readability can be increased by putting each method call on a new line, which is common in JS for chaining:

```
var email = helper.getPeople()
  .find("bob")
  .getEmail();
```

(with various styles of indentation for the subsequent lines)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. The part about not needing a new var statement in the object-chained example makes sense now. Your reply was thorough enough to be included in my notes, thank you again for sharing your knowledge.